# Preg_match sql database connect

Tags: php, sql, database

i was wondering if someone can explain this: i am trying to the php to the SQL and it keeps on failing. Is there something i am missing in the password sector? What should i enter?

```
define('DB_HOST',"localhost");
define('DB_USER', (preg_match("/url.co.cc/i",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"])?"databaseName":"databaseUser"));
define('DB_PASS', (preg_match("/url.co.cc/i",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"])?"password":"password"));
define('DB_NAME', (preg_match("/url.co.cc/i",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"])?"databaseName":"databaseUser"));
```

Comment: How does it fail? What error message do you get? (And I can't really make sense of this code. I'm pretty sure there is a better way to achieve what you want to do)

Comment: Is that code you have got written? If so, please tell what it should do. If not, please explain why you use it. Also you should provide an error message, otherwise it's more an invitation for guessing than a real question.

Comment: No error message, its a database connect. So i uploaded the database on the phpmyadmin and wrote it there. Changed the info so it reflects the new server and the new database name and pw. However, the database the elements which require a database do not work!

Comment: Is that your wordpress configuration file? And how can you say it does not work if you do not get any error message?

Comment: Is there a way to produce error messages via php?

Comment: `var_dump(DB_USER)` etc. to see if they are correct. Otherwise look in the error logs to see if there's an error. This question is unanswerable as is.

Comment: If using regex, also take into account to escape the dot properly: `/url\.co\.cc/i` for matching a literal `.` as it's considered a [metacharcter](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) inside a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think your doing this wrong, try and implement it like so:

```
<?php
$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
```